# iOS - MapKit and navigation from a location to another

Tags: ios, location, mapkit

my question is about the mapkit in the iOS SDK. Is it possible to draw routes from a location to another? Is there any built-in API? If no, how can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about driving the driving route, such as what you would see in the Maps app? Or are you just talking about drawing a line or other route that you yourself are calculating? Because typically to get the driving route/directions you would have to go to the Maps app.

Comment: Both. Is there a way to draw a route as in the Maps app? If no, how can I calculate by myself a route between two locations?

Comment: @Gautham: Hi, try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7, there is an API for getting the direction from a location to another called `MKDirection`. You can call `-[MKDirection calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:]` method for that. This method's argument is `MKDirectionsHandler` block which contains the `MKDirectionsResponse`. The `MKDirectionsResponse` contains the routes data which is array of `MKRoute`. In each `MKRoute` there is a `polyline` (`MKPolyline`) which you can add these `polyline` as overlays to the `MKMapView`.

Answer (score 0):

MKDirections allows you to find routes between two locations and MapKit allows you to add this routes as an overlay.

```
func drawRoutes(sourceLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D , 
destinationLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D)
{

    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation, addressDictionary: nil)


    let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)


    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
    directionRequest.destination = destinationMapItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .automobile


    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)


    directions.calculate {
        (response, error) -> Void in

        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }

            return
        }

        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.mapView.add((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)

        let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
    }
}
```